# Programacion en Android con Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

¿Que temas y/o conceptos de Java necesito saber para poder empezar a programar apps con un cierto grado de complejidad en Android?

Comment: Pues prácticamente todo Java a excepción de las partes gráficas de Java (Swing y AWT). Pero interfaces, encapsulación, herencias, hilos, y más, es completamente necesario. Incluso, aquellas partes que no son expresamente iguales, es conveniente haberlas hecho en Java, pues saber como funcionan son un grado a tu favor. Pero Android no es solo Java, también XML. Un lenguaje de etiquetas que debes conocer para trabajar con las vistas. También, debes saber que no toda aplicación que corre en Java es nativa, también las hay híbridas, es decir, que podría ser una mezcla entre web y nativa, sobre tod

Comment: Más que java, para apps con cierta complejidad, es mejor un buen patrón de diseño

Comment: Te recomiendo que te consigas un libro de guía práctica para el desarrollo en Android. Una vez que te sientas cómodo iría familiarizandome con las buenas prácticas de desarrollo en Android y en desarrollo en general, patrones de diseño, clean architecture, por ejemplo.
Ten paciencia en el aprendizaje y buen viaje!

Comment: Te recomiendo [hermosaprogramacion.com](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com), es una excelente página, en castellano, con más de 50 tutoriales completos, bien hechos, muy claros, sobre casi todo lo que quisieras hacer en Android, desde cosas sencillas, hasta aplicaciones completas con un cierto nivel de complejidad. Para empezar y para avanzar en Android es excelente. Para que no te pierdas en la página, [puedes comenzar por aquí](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/android/).